# Is there any way to get upload image remaing time using dio?

Tags: flutter

I am uploading image using Dio. I got the upload progress in percentage but I also want
to get the upload reaming time.

```
onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
    uploadProgress.value = "${(sent / total * 100).toStringAsFixed (0)}%";
},
```

Is there any way to get the reaming time ?

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the remaining file size to megabytes.
- Convert upload speed to megabytes.
- file size / (uploads per second / 8 )
- ex) 200M/(10M/8) = 160 seconds

##### I simulated an upload environment, I believe you can apply it to the Dio environment, good luck.

```
void test() {
    var totalSize = 120000.0;
    var uploadSpeed = 0.0;
    var timeLeft = 0.0;
    var startTime = DateTime.now();
    var curTime = DateTime.now();
    Timer? timer;
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      if (t.tick > 9) timer?.cancel();
      curTime = DateTime.now();
      var currentSize = 1500。0;
      var usedTime =
          ((curTime.difference(startTime).inMilliseconds) / 1000).toInt();
      uploadSpeed = (totalSize / usedTime) / 1024;
      totalSize = totalSize - currentSize;
      timeLeft = totalSize / (currentSize / 8);
      print('useTime : $usedTime');
      print('uploadSpeed : $uploadSpeed');
      print('File Size : $totalSize');
      print('uploadSpeed :$uploadSpeed');
      print('timeLeft $timeLeft');
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you give me any complete example ?

Comment: @PravinFofariya  yes i modified the answer